# button click method doesn't work as it's visibility changes

Tags: c#

I have a picturebox(called pic_Image) and 2 buttons(called btn_AddImage & btn_RemoveImage). I want to make the buttons visible as user moves the mouse on the pic_Image and make them invisibe as mouse leaves the pic_Image.
this is the code for making visible:

```
private void pic_Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        btn_AddImage.Visible = true;
        btn_RemoveImage.Visible = true;
    }
```

and this is the code for making invisible:

```
private void pic_Image_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_AddImage.Visible = false;
        btn_RemoveImage.Visible = false;
    }
```

The problem is that after I use the pic_Image_MouseMove method the Onbutton click method doesn't work.

thanks in advance

Comment: Seem like when you click on the button, `pic_Image_MouseLeave` fired instead of button onclick event

Comment: I don't understand the conditional in your `MouseMove` handler - it just repeats the same assignment that's immediately before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse movie events continuously fires until mouse is on picture 
Replace mouse move with mouse enter

```
private void pic_Image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    btn_AddImage.Visible = true;
    btn_RemoveImage.Visible = true;
    if (pic_Image.Image != null)
        btn_RemoveImage.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I think even MouseOver can also be used.